# MathJaX, Javascript, software LaTeX to create a .tex file similar of a video online?

Tags: packages, animations, animate, tools, software

I formulate this question because I am very curiosity how this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dOM8EHJoCE) in Italian language has been realized with `LaTeX` or I think `MathJaX` with drop-down menus and graphics.

[image]

Some users can kindly give me a comment, an answer because I really like the way it was made.